# Regex Expressions for Alphanumeric and Wild characters

Tags: regex, alphanumeric

I need to validate / search / find strings as below using regex pattern:

```
1/0.abc
1/0.ABC
1/2/1.xyz
1/.ddd
```

Can Someone help me with the regex pattern please

Comment: You need to explain your question a bit more. What are the possible characters that would occur before the first `/` symbol and also the characters that would occur after the first `/` symbol. And how many `/` symbols are allowed?

Comment: Avinash - All possible combinations are above. Only numbers are allowed before and after the / as its a sample subinterface value on a router. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need this :

```
^\d(?:\/\d)*\/?\.\w+$
```

this will validate your string with any type of extension

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/qE7gK5/1

in java :

```
^\\d(?:\\/\d)*\\/?\\.\\w+$
```

Comment: Thanks aelor , this link is useful. However , as I can see this pattern is valid for php. Can you help me with the one that can be used in java ?

Comment: not very sure, but the same thing with doubly escaped slashes will work. I will check and get back to you

Comment: Thanks @aelor , that will be helpful

Comment: @BhavinBhatia okay thats in java so ?

Comment: Hi ,
For below regular expression , if the I/p string is : 1/0.101 its recognizing it as an alphanumeric which is not the case.

^\\d(?:\\/\\d)*\\/?\\.\\w+$

And below one :

\\b(\\d+/)+\\d*\\.[A-Za-z]{4}\\b compels me to use only 4 characters after the dot which is not my requirement.

Could someone help please ?
Expected result should be :

For - 1/0/1.101 or 1/1/1.22 or anything containing only numbers should be returned as Non alphanumeric and if anything that contains a word / alphabet needs to be flagged as Alphabetic

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language, the pattern may vary. For JavaScript, the following pattern [will work](http://regex101.com/r/nH9lJ2/1):

```
/(\d+\/)+\d*\.[a-z]{3}/ig
```

Comment: I want this in java . Thanks hjpotter92

Comment: @BhavinBhatia For Java, the pattern string shall be: `"(\\d+\\/)+\d*\\.[a-z]{3}"`

Comment: you don't need to escape forward slash.

Comment: Java regex would be: `"\\b(\\d+/)+\\d*\\.[a-z]{3}\\b"`

Comment: "^[0-9](?:\\/[0-9])*\\/?\\.\\w+$ - This worked as well :)
Thank you very much for your valuable feedback